# How to create a volatile table in this case?

Tags: sql

```
sel *A union all sel * B union all sel * C
```

I need this statement result in a table for calculation
A,B,C contains same columns but different values

Comment: provide your schema and expected output in tabular form.

Comment: can u please show me in query ..Sorry i didnt get ur words #newtosql

Comment: A,B,C Tables are volatile tables @zealous

Comment: That's not even valid sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by volatile but if you are looking for the results of your query in one table you can use something like the below

```
   INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE
   SELECT * FROM A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM B
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM C;
```

If you dont want duplicate values you can replace `UNION ALL` by `UNION`

Comment: Thanku ..i got it:)